# Trace how Prolog finds result for query

Tags: debugging, prolog, trace

I am studying for my AI exam I have coming up tomorrow and I was stuck on a particular Prolog question.

The question is as follows:

Consider the following program:

```
r([], X, X).
r([X|Y], X2, X3) :- 
   r(Y, [X|X2], X3).
```

Trace how Prolog would find the result of the following query:

`? - r([1,2,6], [], L).`

We have to trace this by hand, I remember small parts, I wrote this in Prolog and got the answer but can't see where the answer came from.

P. S. I've used the `trace` operator, it showed me the steps but didn't show which functions were fired.

Thank you all!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you capture the trace to a file as outlined after this section then add line annotations to your code and correlate the code lines with the trace you will get something like this.

```
r([1,2,6], [], L)        % Goal

r([], X, X).             % Line 1
r([X|Y], X2, X3) :-      % Line 2
   r(Y, [X|X2], X3).     % Line 3
```

```
Call:  (11)       r([1, 2, 6], []       , _32640   )  % Goal
Unify: (11)       r([1, 2, 6], []       , _32640   )  % Line: 2 
Call:    (12)     r([2, 6]   , [1]      , _32640   )  % Line: 3 
Unify:   (12)     r([2, 6]   , [1]      , _32640   )  % Line: 2
Call:      (13)   r([6]      , [2, 1]   , _32640   )  % Line: 3
Unify:     (13)   r([6]      , [2, 1]   , _32640   )  % Line: 2
Call:        (14) r([]       , [6, 2, 1], _32640   )  % Line: 3
Unify:       (14) r([]       , [6, 2, 1], [6, 2, 1])  % Line: 1
Exit:        (14) r([]       , [6, 2, 1], [6, 2, 1])  % Line: 1
Exit:      (13)   r([6]      , [2, 1]   , [6, 2, 1])  % Line: 3
Exit:    (12)     r([2, 6]   , [1]      , [6, 2, 1])  % Line: 3
Exit:  (11)       r([1, 2, 6], []       , [6, 2, 1])  % Line: 3
```

---

Using [protocol/0](http://protocol/1) to capture trace to a file.

File: `examples.pl`

```
:- module(examples,
    [
        example/1
    ]).

r([], X, X).
r([X|Y], X2, X3) :-
   r(Y, [X|X2], X3).

example(1) :-
    r([1,2,6], [], L),
    format('~w~n',[L]).
```

Example run

```
Welcome to SWI-Prolog (threaded, 64 bits, version 8.3.28-20-g6f8a68f2b)
SWI-Prolog comes with ABSOLUTELY NO WARRANTY. This is free software.
Please run ?- license. for legal details.

For online help and background, visit https://www.swi-prolog.org
For built-in help, use ?- help(Topic). or ?- apropos(Word).

?- working_directory(_,'C:/Users/Groot').
true.

?- [examples].
true.

?- set_prolog_flag(color_term,false).
true.

?- leash(-all), visible(+all).
true.

?- protocol("./trace_output.txt").
true.

?- trace.
true.

[trace]  ?- example(1).
   Call: (10) examples:example(1)
   Unify: (10) examples:example(1)
   Call: (11) examples:r([1, 2, 6], [], _32640)
   Unify: (11) examples:r([1, 2, 6], [], _32640)
   Call: (12) examples:r([2, 6], [1], _32640)
   Unify: (12) examples:r([2, 6], [1], _32640)
   Call: (13) examples:r([6], [2, 1], _32640)
   Unify: (13) examples:r([6], [2, 1], _32640)
   Call: (14) examples:r([], [6, 2, 1], _32640)
   Unify: (14) examples:r([], [6, 2, 1], [6, 2, 1])
   Exit: (14) examples:r([], [6, 2, 1], [6, 2, 1])
   Exit: (13) examples:r([6], [2, 1], [6, 2, 1])
   Exit: (12) examples:r([2, 6], [1], [6, 2, 1])
   Exit: (11) examples:r([1, 2, 6], [], [6, 2, 1])
^  Call: (11) format('~w~n', [[6, 2, 1]])
[6,2,1]
^  Exit: (11) format('~w~n', [[6, 2, 1]])
   Exit: (10) examples:example(1)
true.

[trace]  ?- nodebug.
true.

?- noprotocol.
true.
```

File: `trace_output.txt`

```
true.

?- trace.


true.

[trace]  ?- example(1).


   Call: (10) examples:example(1)
   Unify: (10) examples:example(1)
   Call: (11) examples:r([1, 2, 6], [], _32640)
   Unify: (11) examples:r([1, 2, 6], [], _32640)
   Call: (12) examples:r([2, 6], [1], _32640)
   Unify: (12) examples:r([2, 6], [1], _32640)
   Call: (13) examples:r([6], [2, 1], _32640)
   Unify: (13) examples:r([6], [2, 1], _32640)
   Call: (14) examples:r([], [6, 2, 1], _32640)
   Unify: (14) examples:r([], [6, 2, 1], [6, 2, 1])
   Exit: (14) examples:r([], [6, 2, 1], [6, 2, 1])
   Exit: (13) examples:r([6], [2, 1], [6, 2, 1])
   Exit: (12) examples:r([2, 6], [1], [6, 2, 1])
   Exit: (11) examples:r([1, 2, 6], [], [6, 2, 1])
^  Call: (11) format('~w~n', [[6, 2, 1]])
[6,2,1]
^  Exit: (11) format('~w~n', [[6, 2, 1]])
   Exit: (10) examples:example(1)
true.

[trace]  ?- nodebug.


true.

?- noprotocol.
```

---

Answer (score 0):

If you use [SWI prolog tracer](https://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/man?section=debugoverview) you can execute step by step your procedure and it will show you the current goal and the backtrace (sort of call stack) if requested.

Just issue a `trace.` followed by the call to your goal `r([1,2,6], [], L).`

You can follow step by step the execution of the goal by pressing **Enter** and print the current backtrace by pressing **g**

You can also use the graphical tracer issuing `gtrace.` instead of `trace.`. Using the graphical tracer allows you to see the call stack and each frame's variable bindings.

To end tracing you may call `nodebug.`

Comment: Thank you Gus, I am aware of the ```trace``` operation but didn't use ```gtrace``` before. My problem is that I find it difficult to understand the trace itself. Our lecturer showed us how to do it by hand, I understand the logic of the process but not the manual tracing steps.

Comment: In your example what is "missing" is when the prolog processor would test for the first clause when doing the recursive call and it still isn't the base case. Theoretically it would try to bind for example [2,3] with [] which will fail and then try the second clause. Apart from that the tracer will show exactly where you are, the variable bindings and the backtrace if you ask it.

Comment: Note that I answered from a practical point of view (using a debugger). To see how to do it "on paper" by hand I believe you are better reading some book chapter on the subject.

Comment: That's exactly my problem, the tracer didn't show that it skipped over the first clause. I have an example written out already but you mentioning that really helps. Main question, in the second clause, will Prolog first split lists into variables in ```r([X|Y)...``` before it enters the functor itself?

Comment: It seems tricky, here a sketch. Prolog would try to unify the first argument in the call `Y` with the first parameter of the head of the first clause `[]`. Now suppose `Y` in the first recursive call which has `[2,6]`. So it really is a term `.`/2 (a list with head `2` and tail `[6]`) so it won't unify with the term `[]`/0 as the have different functors, so It would try the second clause which is the term `.`/2 (a list with head `X` and tail `Y`. Now these have the same functor and arity so it will unify `X` with `2` and `Y` with `[6]`. The binding continues for the other parameters/arguments.